# Dart String Interpolation - $ started variables

Tags: dart

How we can use a variable started with `$` in a string interpolation?

What is a string interpolation equivalent of the following string concatenation?

```dart
final String $foo = 'Foo';

print('my variable is '+ $foo);
```

Note: it is useful when we have a variable started with `_` and want to make it public, i.e a JSON field named `_` , can be converted to `$_` in dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
final String $foo = 'Foo';

print('my variable is ${$foo}');
```

Comment: No , we have `Undefined name 'foo'` error, because you interpolate `foo` variable, not `$foo`

Comment: Dartpad must be bugged then https://dartpad.dev/d43875ba1f58f264c7884a81c191cdc4

Comment: you have `final String foo` not `final String $foo` , the question is variable staring with `$`